# WP7 design template resources

Tags: windows-phone-7

Are there any resources for "themes" that I can use to build an app with? Something like templatemonster? The default black/white just doesn't fit my fancy and I'm not creative enough to design my own. I found http://wp7designtemplates.codeplex.com/ but it isn't quite what i was looking for. I've found a few other sites, some point to the codeplex project and the rest are all the same black and white screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default black/white just doesn't cut it

The Black&White Metro theme *do* cut it. You should stick to the design-guidelines, and design using the metro design language.

Just because it's black and white, doesn't mean you can't be creative.

Some example screenshots from some of my apps:

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/WP7/goto/ss1.png
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/WP7/goto/ss4.png
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/WP7/beer/ss2.png
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/WP7/videovideo/ss1.png

Why would you pick another art-style than Metro for things like this? It's all about integrating Metro in your layout. And nobody says you have to stick to black&white, you can also use colours, just stick to a single theme colour (like my first two images, I used a style of pink).

The rest is up to your imagination. UI design / UX comes with practice. And it's a very important part of designing mobile applications.

Comment: Those a pretty nice. My goal is to not have a blocky/cookie cutter looking layout.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll end up with such in the end. If you're used to other platforms, I would recommend you try to design to the light (white) theme first, as it sometimes can be easier to be creative with colours on a white background.